# What representation should I use in Pandas for data valid throughout an interval?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a series of hourly prices. Each price is valid throughout the whole 1-hour period. **What is the best way to represent these prices in Pandas that would enable me to index them in arbitrary higher frequencies (such as minutes or seconds) and do arithmetic with them?**

### Data specifics

Sample prices might be:

```
>>> prices = Series(randn(5), pd.date_range('2013-01-01 12:00', periods = 5, freq='H'))
>>> prices
2013-01-01 12:00:00   -1.001692
2013-01-01 13:00:00   -1.408082
2013-01-01 14:00:00   -0.329637
2013-01-01 15:00:00    1.005882
2013-01-01 16:00:00    1.202557
Freq: H
```

Now, what representation to use if I want the value at `13:37:42`(I expect it to be the same as at 13:00)?

```
>>> prices['2013-01-01 13:37:42']
...
KeyError: <Timestamp: 2013-01-01 13:37:42>
```

### Resampling

I know I could resample the prices and fill in the details (`ffill`, right?), but that doesn't seem like such a nice solution, because I have to assume the frequency I'm going to be indexing it at and it reduces readability with too many unnecessary data points.

### Time spans

At first glance a `PeriodIndex` seems to work

```
>>> price_periods = prices.to_period()
>>> price_periods['2013-01-01 13:37:42']
-1.408082
```

But a time-spanned series doesn't offer some of the other functionality I expect from a `Series`. Say that I have another series `amounts` that says how many items I bought in a certain moment. If I wanted to calculate the prices I would want to multiply the two series'

```
>>> amounts = Series([1,2,2], pd.DatetimeIndex(['2013-01-01 13:37', '2013-01-01 13:57', '2013-01-01 14:05']))
>>> amounts*price_periods
```

but that yields an exception and sometimes even freezes my IPy Notebook. Indexing doesn't help either.

```
>>> ts_periods[amounts.index]
```

Are `PeriodIndex` structures still a work in progress or these features aren't going to be added? Is there maybe some other structure I should have used (or should use for now, before `PeriodIndex` matures)? I'm using Pandas version `0.9.0.dev-1e68fd9`.

Comment: just a comment: Why use 0.9.0.dev if there's an official 0.10.0?

Comment: Good note. I haven't noticed that there was a newer version out. I installed Pandas a couple of months ago through the SciPySuperpack. I upgraded to 0.10.0 now, but now I'm getting a KeyError even with `price_periods['2013-01-01 13:37:42']`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [`asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.asof.html?highlight=asof#pandas.Series.asof)

```
prices.asof('2013-01-01 13:37:42')
```

returns the value for the previous available datetime:

```
prices['2013-01-01 13:00:00']
```

To make calculations, you can use:

```
prices.asof(amounts.index) * amounts
```

which returns a Series with amount's Index and the respective values:

```
>>> prices
2013-01-01 12:00:00    0.943607
2013-01-01 13:00:00   -1.019452
2013-01-01 14:00:00   -0.279136
2013-01-01 15:00:00    1.013548
2013-01-01 16:00:00    0.929920

>>> prices.asof(amounts.index)
2013-01-01 13:37:00   -1.019452
2013-01-01 13:57:00   -1.019452
2013-01-01 14:05:00   -0.279136

>>> prices.asof(amounts.index) * amounts
2013-01-01 13:37:00   -1.019452
2013-01-01 13:57:00   -2.038904
2013-01-01 14:05:00   -0.558272
```

Comment: That solves the 1st issue I am having (same as the `PeriodIndex` does), but can I somehow use it to do arithmetic with the series? I wouldn't know how to achieve `amounts*prices` without a for loop, which is not the Pandas way.

Comment: thanks. Indeed it works, though a bit hackety for my taste. Let's see if there will be some other opinions.